# Can newer versions of MSBuild compile older C# solutions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I've inherited a set of build scripts which currently look inside the .sln file, work out what version of Visual Studio they were created with, and then call the version of MSBuild associated with that version of VS.

Is that necessary?  Or will the latest version of MSBuild compile older solutions/projects?

Comment: VS can compile old projects so I think so, not sure that's why I won't post this as answer

Comment: I'm curious why this has been downvoted with no explanation.  If I've asked a stupid question then I'd like to know why it's stupid.

Comment: I would expect so.  id give it  a try and see what happens

Comment: I have a couple of hundred applications. I'd rather be sure that there aren't odd corner cases and not have to run them all through and test they haven't broken in subtle ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can newer versions of MSBuild compile older C# solutions?

The simple answer is yes.

When building the project from Visual Studio, Visual Studio will call `devenv.exe` to build the project, then devenv calls msbuild to perform the build.

As per official document [Port, Migrate, and Upgrade Visual Studio Projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects):

> **Each new version of Visual Studio generally supports most previous types of projects, files, and other assets. You can work with them as
>   you always have, and provided that you don't depend on newer features,
>   Visual Studio preserves backwards compatibility with previous versions
>   like Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, and Visual Studio 2012.**
>
> **Support for some types change over time, however. A newer version of Visual Studio may no longer support certain types, or require that
>   they be migrated and updated such that they're no longer
>   backwards-compatible.**

So the latest version of MSBuild supports most previous types of older solutions/projects except those no longer support by the newer version of MSBuild.